# How to name the @ForeignKey when using @IdClass composite primary key?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MyPK.class)
public class SubEntity {
    @Id private int id;
    @Id private String name;
}

@Entity
public class ParentEntity {
    @OneToOne(cascade = ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_sub_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_sub"))
    private SubEntity sub;
}
```

`Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering SubEntity from ParentEntity has the wrong number of column. should be 2`

This fails due to the `@JoinColumn` annotation. But how do I have to write it for a composite PK? I have to use this annotation to set the foreignkey constraint name during `hibernate` auto generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For composite keys you should use @JoinColumns

```
@JoinColumns(value = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_sub_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_name", referencedColumnName = "name")},
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_sub"))
```

Update:

Hibernate seems to not have followed the JPA 2.1 specification in this instance. You'll need to additionally include hibernates own annotation which is deprecated but still functions. This should be added like:

```
@JoinColumns(value = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_sub_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_name", referencedColumnName = "name")},
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_sub"))
@org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey(name = "fk_sub")
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still generates a random constraint name: `CONSTRAINT fk_ofks1hyry3g2fxi2dvd8l9xv0 FOREIGN KEY (fk_sub_id, fk_name)`

Comment: You are correct, it looks like hibernate isn't following the JPA 2.1 specification in this instance. I've updated my answer to provide a work around for hibernate.